# Lets say you want to run an if/else condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to run this code to print a value based on certain conditions, but its only printing one value. Here is the code:

```js
let instagramlikes;
let sitetraffic;
let dailytraffic;

function clientwidgets(x) {
  if (x === instagramlikes) {
    console.log("This is A");
  } else if (x === sitetraffic) {
    console.log("This is B");
  } else if (x === dailytraffic) {
    console.log("This is C")
  }
};

console.log(clientwidgets(instagramlikes));
console.log(clientwidgets(sitetraffic));
console.log(clientwidgets(dailytraffic));
```

Comment: What values will `instagramLikes` hold? Are they meant to hold values? As of right now they are uninitialized, meaning they all hold a value of `undefined`. And since `undefined === undefined` is true, then `x === instagramLikes` will always be true as well.

Comment: if you do `let instagramlikes = {};
let sitetraffic = {};
let dailytraffic = {};` it will work, since objects do not use value for `==` or `===`, they use reference. Personally i use the object enum method @Asleepace did below

Comment: As Khauri asks, what is `instagramLikes`? What is `x`? Are they page elements, and you want to find which element was passed? Are they counts, and you want to see which count matches the x that was passed? Asleepace answers the question assuming they are numeric values, but with the function name `clientwidgets(x)` I would guess they are widgets — so your question can't really be answered without more information, except to say all your values are undefined, so the first `if` always matches and the `else if`s will never be tested.

Comment: do you think variables are checked by the name?? `console.log (x, instagramlikes, sitetraffic, dailytraffic)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't *technically* have enums.
If you don't initialize a variable, it is initialized as undefined.

That is to say that the following two statements are exactly the same:

```js
let instagramlikes;
let instagramlikes = undefined
```

And in your function you essentially pass in `x` and `undefined`. This then checks if `x === instagramlikes` which is translated as `undefined === undefined` which will be `true`.

In order to simulate an enum, you might try to set your variables to some value like so:

```js
const instagramlikes = 'instagramlikes';
const sitetraffic = 'sitetraffic';
const dailytraffic = 'dailytraffic';

function clientwidgets(x) {
  if (x === instagramlikes) {
    return "This is A";
  } else if (x === sitetraffic) {
    return "This is B";
  } else if (x === dailytraffic) {
    return "This is C";
  }
};

console.log(clientwidgets(instagramlikes));
console.log(clientwidgets(sitetraffic));
console.log(clientwidgets(dailytraffic));
```

It doesn't have to be a string though, you can use a number or really any object. Such as a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) if the environment you're targeting supports it.

Each instance of a Symbol is unique so comparisons with `===` should work flawlessly.

```js
const instagramlikes = Symbol();
const sitetraffic = Symbol();
const dailytraffic = Symbol();

function clientwidgets(x) {
  if (x === instagramlikes) {
    return "This is A";
  } else if (x === sitetraffic) {
    return "This is B";
  } else if (x === dailytraffic) {
    return "This is C";
  }
};

console.log(clientwidgets(instagramlikes));
console.log(clientwidgets(sitetraffic));
console.log(clientwidgets(dailytraffic));
```

Answer (score 6):

Try assigning a unique value to each of the different options.

```js
let instagramlikes = 1;
let sitetraffic = 2;
let dailytraffic = 3;

function clientwidgets(x){
  if (x === instagramlikes){
    console.log("This is A");
  } else if (x === sitetraffic){
    console.log("This is B");
  } else if (x === dailytraffic){
    console.log("This is C")
  }
}


clientwidgets(instagramlikes);
clientwidgets(sitetraffic);
clientwidgets(dailytraffic);
```

I would create an object enumeration to hold all the types as well:

```
const TYPE = {
  INSTAGRAM_LIKES:1,
  SITE_TRAFFIC:2,
  DAILY_TRAFFIC:3
}
```

and then call like so

```
clientwidgets(TYPE.INSTAGRAM_LIKES);
```

Comment: Yes, I think what the OP is wanting is constants,..  A little tweak to this would be to change the `let` to `const`, and for a nice Javascript convention, change the consts to all uppercase.

Comment: @Keith yup my thoughts too, I added a `TYPE` constant below